# CreateLibrary for CUDA with NVCCCompiler

Tags: librarylink, cudalink

I am currently learning to use CUDA to speed up calculations. The book I am working with uses C code on the CPU to supply certain variables etc.. So I would like to compile the give code in Mathematica. I found an instance for this in the help CUDALink/tutorial/Programming#120112373 chapter **Compiling for CUDA**.

```
Needs["CCompilerDriver`"]
Needs["CUDALink`"]
```

The NVCCComplier is listed after loading the above stated links and the CUDAFunctionLoad is also working. The output of `CCompilers[]` is:

> {{Name->Visual Studio,
> Compiler->CCompilerDriver`VisualStudioCompiler`VisualStudioCompiler,
> CompilerInstallation->C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0,
> CompilerName->Automatic},
> {Name->NVIDIA CUDA Compiler,
> Compiler->NVCCCompiler,
> CompilerInstallation->C:\Users\gbj\AppData\Roaming\Mathematica\
>     Paclets\Repository\CUDAResources-Win64-10.2.0.3\CUDAToolkit\bin\,
> CompilerName->Automatic
> }}

```
testFileName = FileNameJoin[{$CUDALinkPath, "SupportFiles", "cudaDLL.cu"}];
FilePrint[testFileName]
```

Also works fine and gives the same code than listed in the example.
When I try to create a library with

```
CreateLibrary[{testFileName},"testDLL","Compiler"->NVCCCompiler]
```

the return is *$Failed*.

Added:

With ShellOutputFunction->Print as a opition for CreateLibrary I get:

> C:\Users\gbj\AppData\Roaming\Mathematica\SystemFiles\LibraryResources\
>   \Windows-x86-64\Working-goe-nb-0422-7460-5372-11>call "C:\Program \
>   Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat" amd64 
>   Setting environment for using Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 x64 tools.
>   **nvcc fatal   : Unsupported gpu architecture 'compute_51'**

Edit:
`CUDAInformation[]` gives:

> {1->{Name->NVS 5200M,Clock Rate->1344000,Compute Capabilities->2.1,GPU Overlap->1,Maximum Block Dimensions->{1024,1024,64},Maximum Grid Dimensions->{65535,65535,65535},Maximum Threads Per Block->1024,Maximum Shared Memory Per Block->49152,Total Constant Memory->65536,Warp Size->32,Maximum Pitch->2147483647,Maximum Registers Per Block->32768,Texture Alignment->512,Multiprocessor Count->2,Core Count->64,Execution Timeout->1,Integrated->False,Can Map Host Memory->True,Compute Mode->Default,Texture1D Width->65536,Texture2D Width->65536,Texture2D Height->65535,Texture3D Width->2048,Texture3D Height->2048,Texture3D Depth->2048,Texture2D Array Width->16384,Texture2D Array Height->16384,Texture2D Array Slices->2048,Surface Alignment->512,Concurrent Kernels->True,ECC Enabled->False,TCC Enabled->False,Total Memory->1073741824}}

`CUDAResourcesInformation[]` returns

> {{Name->CUDAResources,Version->10.2.0.3,BuildNumber->,Qualifier->Win64,WolframVersion->10.*,SystemID->{Windows-x86-64},Description->{ToolkitVersion -> 7.0, MinimumDriver -> 300.0},Category->,Creator->,Publisher->,Support->,Internal->False,Location->C:\Users\gbj\AppData\Roaming\Mathematica\Paclets\Repository\CUDAResources-Win64-10.2.0.3,Context->{},Enabled->True,Loading->Manual,Hash->7326e294f5e53407e2ce826e5b3ce301}}

---

I have no idea why that is and what to do to make it work.
Two questions I have now:

1) Can someone give a hint what to do to make it work?

Maybe someone can test it on his machine and confirm it is working in general.

2) Why is this CreateLibrary compiling a DLL and not a lib which I could load with LibraryFunctionLoad?->answered

My system: Windows 7 (64bit), CUDA 7.5.18 installed, MM 10.3, Microsoft Visual Studio 2010

Comment: It is working for me with Mathematica 10.3.1 on Windows 10 with Visual Studio 2012. Can you compile to C (non-CUDA) with your setup? Also try using the option `"ShellOutputFunction" -> Print` in CreateLibrary.

Comment: Regarding 2), the DLL *is* a library which you can load with LibraryFunctionLoad.

Comment: Thank you for testing. I am supprised that CUDA compilation works with Visual Studio 2012. I had it also installed but it was recognized by the CUDA toolkit installation (7.5). Which one do you use? The pure c-compilation I need to test, but I have to find some code first.

Comment: I have toolkit version 6.0 here. To test compiling to C just use something simple like `Compile[{x}, x + 1, CompilationTarget -> "C"]`

Comment: I just tried something more complex and compiled the mandelbulb instance from Mathematica starting with the demo_numerical.c file and CreateLibrary and then doing the LibraryFunctionLoad. That works without issues. So C-compilation does work.

Comment: Can you include the output of `CUDAInformation[]` and `CUDAResourcesInformation[]`?

Comment: I added the results above.

Comment: I updated CUDAResources to version 10.2.0.3 and got the same problem. I think I have a solution, will post an answer shortly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got the same error, but only after updating the CUDA Resources to version 10.2.0.3.

The problem seems to come about due to the inclusion of **-gencode=arch=compute_ 51,code=compute_ 51** in the nvcc command line. This is hardcoded into the definition of `` CUDALink`NVCCCompiler`Private`ResolveCUDAArchitecture `` when the `"CUDAArchitecture"` option is `Automatic` (the default).

You can check this with:

```
CUDALink`NVCCCompiler`Private`ResolveCUDAArchitecture[CreateLibrary, 1, {}]
```

> -gencode=arch=compute_20,code=compute_20
>   -gencode=arch=compute_30,code=compute_30
>   -gencode=arch=compute_35,code=compute_35
>   -gencode=arch=compute_50,code=compute_50
>   -gencode=arch=compute_51,code=compute_51
>   -gencode=arch=compute_52,code=compute_52

The issue is that 5.1 is not one of the supported Compute Capability version numbers. See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CUDA#Supported_GPUs) or [this](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#features-and-technical-specifications__technical-specifications-per-compute-capability) for example.

There are two workarounds that solve the problem for me:

Workaround 1 - specify the target architecture explicitly with the `"CUDAArchitecture"` option. For example:

```
CreateLibrary[{testFileName}, "testDLL", 
 "Compiler" -> NVCCCompiler, "CUDAArchitecture" -> "sm_21"]
```

Workaround 2 - remove the offending string directly from the definition of `` CUDALink`NVCCCompiler`Private`ResolveCUDAArchitecture ``

```
With[{
   rca = CUDALink`NVCCCompiler`Private`ResolveCUDAArchitecture,
   bad = "  -gencode=arch=compute_51,code=compute_51"},
  DownValues[rca] = DeleteCases[DownValues[rca], bad, -1]];
```

-> Option for CUDA architecture is here: http://codeyarns.com/2014/03/03/how-to-specify-architecture-to-compile-cuda-code/

Comment: Thank you for taking the time. Great work! I was up to this link (section 5) [link](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-compiler-driver-nvcc/index.html#axzz3wCyA6Qfz). For me solution 1 works but `CreateLibrary` issues an error: >OptionValue::nodef: "Unknown option \!\(\"CUDAArchitecture\"\) for CreateLibrary.". Anyhow, it still creates a working DLL. How did you find about the option `CUDAArchitecture`? It is not documented (that was were I got stuck).

Comment: I get the same error. The option is listed in the documentation for `NVCCCompiler` and clearly works in CreateLibrary even though it isn't recognised as an option. I think CUDALink in general is a bit rough around the edges!

Comment: @entropi99 Wouldn't http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-compiler-driver-nvcc/index.html, sections 3.2.7 and 5.4ff, be a better, more authoritative reference?  I voted to approve your edit because the intention seemed helpful and the OP can always override; and I would like you to feel welcome to participate on the site. But edits really should be more substantial. Perhaps it would have been better left as a comment?

Comment: Hi Michael, Thanks for that. I couldn't comment at that time (need at least 50 reps to able to comment). The link from nvidia has a lot of information which may confuse a bit. But I agree with you.

Comment: It seems 14.0 has broken this. ```CUDALink`NVCCCompiler`Private`ResolveCUDAArchitecture[CreateLibrary, 1, {}]``` now just results in: ```CreateLibrary::invcub: The "CreateCUBIN" option set to CreateCUBIN is not valid. "CreateCUBIN" must be either True or False.```